# Where can official Latvian swimming locations (and their current water temperatures) be found?

Tags: weather-and-climate, water-sports, latvia

**Where can maps of official swimming locations in Latvia be found? These would be better if they also included temperatures at those locations.**

---

I've tried searching different options, incl. translating "water", "water temperature", etc..., to Latvian in Google Translate in order to find anything like the below map where water temperatures and swimming locations are pictured side-by-side. The same provider also gives info on Latvia, but doesn't have the same layout/pages.

An Estonian sample map is shown below, [from here](https://ilmateade.delfi.ee/rannailm/), which [expands when clicked on any of the point markers](https://ilmateade.delfi.ee/ilm/tallinn/harku-jarv/):

[image]
[image]

---

The best thing I've found thus far is [this news site](https://www.diena.lv/atslegvards/udens-temperatura) which seems to write an article every now and then that the water temperature goes above a certain limit, but it's not comprehensive and it's not current (for most locations).

The 'official' (as much as I've been able to figure out) Latvian MetOffice site has [this under 'water temperature'](https://www.meteo.lv/laika-prognoze-jurai/udens-temperatura/?nid=559):

[image]

Google Translate turns this into a 'coastal temperature' instead (with no mention to water unless it's getting something wrong—more than probable):

> 06.08. Variable amount of clouds, there will be less clouds per day. Precipitation is not expected, but in some places fog may form in some places. A slow wind will blow. Air t. N: + 9… + 14 °, on the coast + 12… + 17 °, D: + 22… + 27 °, on the coast + 20… + 23 °. In Riga without precipitation, t. N: + 12… + 14 °, D: + 25… + 26 °.

Note: I would have downsized the examples, but didn't know how to fix their width. They are illustrative only of what I was hoping to find.

Comment: As a former inhabitant of the other side of the Baltic Sea, I've found that it only has two temperatures, "freezing" and "almost freezing".  Inland lakes can, of course, get a bit warmer in summer.

Comment: Having swum in the Baltic Sea in Usedom a couple of years ago, I concur.  It was August and warm enough outside (at least the first few days), but the water was utterly frigid.

Comment: See if you can find tide gauge information. Here's one for La Jolla, California which does have the water temperature: https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/stationhome.html?id=9410230#obs

Comment: Related: [Drowning deaths plague Latvia](https://eng.lsm.lv/article/society/society/drowning-deaths-plague-latvia.a91154/). Outdoor swimming claims almost 8 times more lives than people who suffer lethal accidents in and around bodies of water in the European Union.